# Node.js Express Asyn/await

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

Okay, i am not entirely sure what i am doing wrong.

I have to do multiple SQL query's, and i really don't want them all nested within each other. So i am trying to work with Async/Await so that i can call my query's as functions instead.

The thing is, that it seems like my function doesn't get to finish before it continues, although i have written await in front.

If i try to call my "test" function, it does return the string "text" for me to console log.

I have also tried to add "async" in front of my "get_all_events" function.

I hope someone can help me out

```
const db_connection = require('../../helpers/db/db_config.js').connect_local()

module.exports = function (server) {
    server.get('/events', async function(req, res, next) {
            try {
                var event_data = await get_all_events()
                console.log("Try Catch CL: ", event_data)

                res.render('public assets/pages/events', {
                    event_data  : event_data
                });

            } catch (error) {

            }      
        }
    );
}
function test(){
    return "test"
}
function get_all_events () {
    let sql_get_all_events = `
        SELECT event_id, event_name, event_text, event_dateStart, event_dateEnd, event_imagePath, type_id, type_name, type_text, type_imagePath, type_color,seating_id
        FROM 
            ((tb_events 
        INNER JOIN 
            tb_event_types ON type_id = fk_event_type)
        INNER JOIN 
            tb_seating ON seating_id = fk_seating)`



    db_connection.query(sql_get_all_events, function (error, event_data) {
        if (error) 
            throw(error)
        else
            return event_data
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return `Promise` from your `get_all_events()` function to be able to `await` it:

```
function get_all_events() {
    let sql_get_all_events = `...`;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db_connection.query(sql_get_all_events, function (error, event_data) {
            if (error) {
                return reject(error);
            }

            resolve(event_data);
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: Oh thank god! This worked, i really appreciate that, i have been running through so many pages, without being able to find something i could make work / understand right.

You have a really nice evening!

Answer (score 0):

Async/await only works if you are returning a promise.

```
db_connection.query(sql_get_all_events, function (error, event_data) {
    if (error) 
        throw(error)
    else
        return Promise.resolve(event_data)
});
```

see if this works.